# Reusable Column MENU Filter (Kendo for Angular 2+)

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

I'm trying to find the best way to configure the grid filtering options in angular kendo (coming from asp.net telerik stuff). I think I generally have it the way I want, but ran into a problem.

I'm trying to implement this example: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/data-operations/filtering/reusable-filter/

But I want to use filter menus instead of filter rows. So I changed filterable="menu", and kendoGridFilterMenuTemplate, but choosing the dropdown filter now bombs.

Here is an example:

https://plnkr.co/edit/2OI4wk7FaQHwOoJuZjos?p=preview

```
<ng-template kendoGridFilterMenuTemplate let-filter>
            <my-dropdown-filter
                [filter]="filter"
                [data]="distinctCategories"
                textField="CategoryName"
                valueField="CategoryID">
            </my-dropdown-filter>
</ng-template>
```

Any ideas / suggestions on how to make this work?

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone needs this... the kendo folks pointed me in the correct direction. I believe this is just a case of the documentation not catching up yet (there is a new example that is in the dev site that shows exactly what I need).

Summary: when using a filter menu template, you need to pass the filter service and call filterService.filter instead of the apply filter in the onchange event.

Here is the relevant code from the custom filter control / dropdown if anyone needs it:

```js
import {Component, Input, Output} from '@angular/core';
import {CompositeFilterDescriptor} from '@progress/kendo-data-query';
import {FilterService, BaseFilterCellComponent} from '@progress/kendo-angular-grid';

@Component({
  selector: 'grid-dropdown-filter',
  template: `
    <kendo-dropdownlist
      [data]="data"
      (valueChange)="onChange($event)"
      [defaultItem]="defaultItem"
      [value]="selectedValue"
      [valuePrimitive]="true"
      [textField]="textField"
      [valueField]="valueField">
    </kendo-dropdownlist>
  `
})
export class GridDropdownFilterComponent extends BaseFilterCellComponent {
  @Input() public filter: CompositeFilterDescriptor;
  @Input() public filterService: FilterService;
  @Input() public data: any[];  // Dropdown list data
  @Input() public textField: string;
  @Input() public valueField: string;
  @Input() public field: string;
  
  public get selectedValue(): any {
    const filter: any = this.filterByField(this.field);
    return filter ? filter.value : undefined;
  }

  public get defaultItem(): any {
    return {
      [this.textField]: 'Select item...',
      [this.valueField]: undefined
    };
  }

  constructor(filterService: FilterService) {
    super(filterService);
  }

  public onChange(value: any): void {
    this.filter = this.updateFilter({
      field: this.field,
      operator: "eq",
      value: value
    });

    this.filterService.filter(this.filter);
  }
}
```